# Why does this distance query return no results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, gis

I know that the DistanceInMiles function works, I tested it. But why doesn't the query return any results. I'm new to sql so I don't really know how to do complex queries, but I don't know why this isn't working. All of the Items in the database meet the requirements of the query. But it returns 0 row(s) returned.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DistanceInMiles$$
CREATE FUNCTION DistanceInMiles(src_lat decimal(10, 8), src_lng decimal(11, 8), dest_lat decimal(10, 8), dest_lng decimal(11, 8)) 
RETURNS decimal(15, 8) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN CAST((3959 * acos(cos(radians(src_lat)) * cos(radians(dest_lat)) *
    cos(radians(dest_lng) - radians(src_lng)) + sin(radians(src_lat)) *
    sin(radians(dest_lat)))) as decimal(15, 8));
END $$

DELIMITER ;

SET @dist = 2500;

SET @srctLat = 41.024449;

SET @srcLng = -72.481628;

SELECT z.lat, z.lng, z.name, z.restaurant_id,
DistanceInMiles(@srcLat, @srcLng, z.lat, z.lng) as distance
from restaurants z
HAVING distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo.
Change `SET @srctLat = 41.024449;` to `SET @srcLat = 41.024449;`

Comment: @MilesLow It happens to the best of us. If this solves your issue, you should mark it as such. Do note that I did not check your function, I trusted that it works as you said it does.

Comment: @MilesLow I would argue that if this solves your issue, you should delete the question.

Comment: @Strawberry You cant delete a question when have an upvoted answer

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oh well.